# Is "how much ever" correct here?

Tags: word-choice, idioms, expressions

"How much ever you prepare, it is your attitude in the exam hall that matters"

From a previous question concerning the same phrase, I realize "how ever much" could be used.But I am asking this because of 2 reasons.
1. It does seem to make a little sense, that is 
how much- doesn't it imply the level of preparation
and ever- for whatever period of time you might have prepared.
2. I have seen the phrase being used in a lot of sites.

Is there any chance for the phrase to be used by a native speaker of English ?

If I use how ever much, would it mean the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

No, I never heard anyone say that ever. How many times have I heard "how much ever"? Never. Never ever have I heard "how much ever". Some singers say "whatever".

"How much do you prepare?" sounds more natural to me. Additionally, it is not all that matters. The idiom also isn't all that matters yet it is "all that matters", and my source for this one is Metallica song "Nothing Else Matters".

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tAGnKpE4NCI